# OpenSSL C API to implement openssl asn1parse logic

Tags: c, openssl, asn.1, asn1crypto, openssl-cms

Decoded data using openssl asn1parse with the command "openssl asn1parse -in a.pem -out b.pem".
How to implement the same using Openssl C language API.

Comment: "openssl asn1parse -in a.pem "  parses and gives output in correct format.  How to perform the same job using openssl C API ?

Comment: That `asn1parse` command that you gave prints stuff to `stdout` and converts the original input file to its DER-formatted version (so calling it `b.pem` is not right). Also, the `asn1parse` tool can handle ASN.1 files generically, which is probably not what you need to (re-)implement. Can you be more specific about what it exactly is that you have to implement using the c API? Maybe start by defining a c function prototype that shows/documents what your input is and your expected output, as a starting point. Your current question is too vague to be reasonably answerable.

Comment: I have decoded "openssl asn1parse -in a.pem" to get  data. My requirement is to do the same functionality using C API . Can you please suggest which API do I need to use ? I see "ASN1_get_object" and "ASN1_parse_dump" being used. Which API should I use for decoding "openssl asn1parse -in a.pem". Thanks.